# ngBind-Html w/ JSON file

Tags: angularjs, json, ng-bind-html

Im tweaking the Up & Coming with Angularjs videos from Lynda.com.  Currently im trying to utilize ng-bind-html with the ngSanitize feature so that I can keep HTML code in the JSON file.  Here are my current pages, and im not sure how to show them off.

HTML- file

```
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="main" ng-view></div>
</body>
```

App.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'anatomyControllers'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
when('/list', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/list.html',
  controller: 'ListController'
}).
when('/details/:itemId', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/details.html',
  controller: 'DetailsController'
}).
otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/list'
 });
}]);
```

controller.js

```
var anatomyControllers = angular.module('anatomyControllers', ['ngAnimate',        'ngSanitize']);

anatomyControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http',    function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('js/data2.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.anatomy = data;
    $scope.anatomyOrder = 'name';
   });
}]);

anatomyControllers.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope',     '$http','$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
  $http.get('js/data2.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.anatomy = data;
    $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;

    if ($routeParams.itemId > 0) {
      $scope.prevItem = Number($routeParams.itemId)-1;
    } else {
      $scope.prevItem = $scope.anatomy.length-1;
    }

    if ($routeParams.itemId < $scope.anatomy.length-1) {
      $scope.nextItem = Number($routeParams.itemId)+1;
    } else {
      $scope.nextItem = 0;
    }

  });
}]);
```

view

```
<div class="bio">
    <h3>Structure</h3>
      <p ng-bind-html="{{anatomy[whichItem].structure}}"></p>
  </br>
    <h3>Nerve</h3>{{anatomy[whichItem].nerve}}
  </br>
    <h3>Action</h3>{{anatomy[whichItem].action}}
  </div>
```

Currently the Nerve, Action are visible, but the Structures is not showing up.  Its the item im doing the ng-bind-html test on.  Thanks everyone

-T

Comment: ng-bind-html="anatomy[whichItem].structure" must work. Check out the correct way to use it here - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: I tried just following that and the above code is still not working.  So im not sure what Im missing